# Existence of $L^2$ limit of sequence of martingales

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, brownian-motion, martingales

I am currently revising some martingale theory, and was trying out an old [past paper question](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/sites/www.maths.cam.ac.uk/files/pre2014/postgrad/mathiii/pastpapers/2009/Paper31.pdf). I haven't come across anything like this before, so was wondering how one would approach it, and also in general if there are any ways of finding the limit of a sequence of martingales.

> **Question 4**
>
> Assume that $B$ is a 1D Brownian motion from $0$. Define $$ \begin{equation}\tag{1} M^f_t=f(B_t)-f(0)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf^{\prime\prime}(B_s)ds \end{equation} $$ Also define $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}|x|&\text{for }|x|\geq 1/n\\\frac{n}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2n}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ For all
> $n$ you can assume $M^{f_n}$ is a continuous martingale, and that
> moreover
> $$\begin{equation}\tag{2}\mathbb{E}\left[|M^f_t|^2\right]=\int_0^t\mathbb{E}\left[|f^\prime(B_s)|^2\right]ds\end{equation} $$
>
> Show that there is a continuous martingale $M$ s.t. for all $t$,
>
> $$\begin{equation} \mathbb{E}\left[\sup_{s\leq
> > t}|M^{f_n}_s-M_s|^2\right] \to 0\text{ as }n\to\infty\end{equation} $$

I assume the argument is that since the $f_n$ are converging uniformly to $x\mapsto |x|$, then the resulting limit of $M^{f_n}$ is still a continuous martingale, but I am not sure how to make this precise.